# DynamicJasper setting different font style in one line of text for a title

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Is this possible in *DynamicJasper*:

This is a text ( *a simple description* )
Another text ( ***another simple description*** )

I wanted to have a title with that format, but I don't know how to set the font style.
I've been searching but I can't find the solution, hope someone could help.